# Is there a term to describe math problems that have multiple steps?

Tags: terminology

Sometimes, a math question may have multiple steps to it.
For example:
[image]

In this 3 examples, the question is asking the person to solve multiple steps in the problem. It's not like a traditional math problem of this type, where there are only two numbers to be added together.

The example I have given shows 3 addition problems. But it could take the form of subtraction or multiplication as well:
[image]

The terms I have seen are long math, long addition, long subtraction etc. Are these the correct term (or at least the terms which will be most widely understood)? If there isn't a correct term, then what's the best phrase to use.

Audience:
Students (of all ages, including adults). I am making worksheets for my classes and just looking for a good term to describe these problems.

Comment: i think a good term would be ALGORITHM , you can teach your students step by step proof and call it the ¡algorithm of solving.. such operation

Comment: I don't like the subtraction problem because nested subtraction means addition of some terms, so the question may lead to confusion. I've not seen that before and I think it's not a good question.

Comment: What are the answers you are expecting from your students for the subtraction problems?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> "Steps" are not really a thing in mathematics. Here, specifically, you're asking about addition/multiplication with "more than two operands." I don't recall ever hearing these called anything but _sums_ and _products_. <> Separately, as Adam and John note, subtraction and division are not associative, so expressions with more than two operands are _not well-defined_. (E.g., $(1 - 2) - 3 \neq 1 - (2 - 3)$, so asking students to evaluate "$1 - 2 - 3$" is an invitation to ambiguity and confusion.)

Comment: Sounds like you're asking about [**_arity_**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity).  Young students might be first introduced to operands with an arity of 2, e.g. adding 2 numbers.  When generalized to arbitrarily many arguments (numbers), it might be described as $`` n\text{-arity} " ,$ where $n$ is the number of arguments.

Comment: For example, adding arbitrarily many numbers together as part of one operation could be called "_$n\text{-ary}$ addition_".

Comment: BTW, in case any students ask: yes, $n$ can be $0 ,$ $1 ,$ or $2 .$  This is, it's not exclusively about adding many arguments together, just arbitrarily many.  And if a student might find the concept of adding zero numbers together as odd and ask why it might be done, then you can say it's a computer thing -- for example, a computer told to sum together the total price of all items a customer bought in a store might sum zero numbers if a customer didn't buy anything.